# WARNING: No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_core

Tags: yocto

I am working with yocto, I have a freescale yocto image which is provided for us from freescale with fido poky and all its bsp meta layers. Now I want to upgrade this to krogoth.

When I replaced fido poky with krogoth poky. It is giving below error. Even though I have provided all the necessary meta layers in bblayers.conf file

```
 WARNING: No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_core '^/home/a/bsp12/poky/meta/'

 WARNING: No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_yocto '^/home/a/bsp12/poky/meta-poky/'

 WARNING: No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_yoctobsp '^/home/a/bsp12/poky/meta-yocto-bsp/'

 WARNING: No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_fsl-arm '^/home/a/bsp12/meta-fsl-arm/'

 WARNING: No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_fsl-networking '^/home/a/bsp12/meta-fsl-networking/'

 ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'fsl-image-core'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is this `ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'fsl-image-core'`.  You are missing this recipe when you replaced the files.  Not `BBFILE_PATTERN`; Although this told that you did not replace the files completely.

In addition, the use of BBFILE_PATTERN can be found on all meta-data layer configuration;
e.g.: bsp/sources/poky/meta-yocto/conf/layer.conf

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH =. "${LAYERDIR}:"

# We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "yocto"
BBFILE_PATTERN_yocto = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_yocto = "5"

# This should only be incremented on significant changes that will
# cause compatibility issues with other layers
LAYERVERSION_yocto = "2"

LAYERDEPENDS_yocto = "core"
```

> The first thing BitBake does is parse base configuration metadata.
>   Base configuration metadata consists of the bblayers.conf file to
>   determine what layers BitBake needs to recognize, all necessary
>   layer.conf files (one from each layer), and bitbake.conf. The data
>   itself is of various types;
>
> The layer.conf files are used to construct key variables such as
>   BBPATH and BBFILES. BBPATH is used to search for configuration and
>   class files under conf/ and class/ directories, respectively. BBFILES
>   is used to find recipe files (.bb and .bbappend). If there is no
>   bblayers.conf file, it is assumed the user has set the BBPATH and
>   BBFILES directly in the environment.

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#parsing-the-base-configuration-metadata

Comment: Thanks Fro your reply Charles,  I included the all the necessary recipes too, one observation what i saw is, i intentionally included meta-intel and gave MACHINE ??= "mohonpeak64", it is taking that recipe at that time, but when i give MACHINE ??= 's32v234evb', it is not able to find the recipe, even though this s32v234evb.conf file is present inside meta-fsl-s32v which i already included in bblayers.conf

Comment: It is really hard to debug since you have multiple recipes coming from different sources that you didn't list;  In addition to that, yours meta-data is not publicly available on open-embedded;  

My suggestion is to clean up the build with "bitbake -c cleansstate " or delete the whole tmp dir;